# Removing lower links in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to remove the lower links in Magento. For example using the blank theme it will show:

```
Privacy and Cookie Policy <br/>
Search Terms <br/>
Contact Us <br/>
Orders and Returns <br/>
Advanced Search
```

To remove the top links I added this to my default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
```

Is there a name I am missing? I have tried things like bottom.links, footer.links, ect. Everything I can think of and still no luck. Is it a name space I am missing?

Comment: I could not get chance to check M2 but can you please look at CMS and Static blocks? i hope you will find solution there.

Answer (score 2):

Name of your block as `footer_links`

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

You can add this code in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Comment: PaW@ I tried but not working at file location app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: What is theme your store using now ?

Comment: magento 2 default theme "luma"

Comment: you should add my code in app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml and try again

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Are you clear cache ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32035/discussion-between-abdul-and-paw).

Comment: I tried using footer_links and still no luck. Is there anything else I could be missing?

Comment: I have also tried to remove report a bug link from footer by placing default.xml file under app/design/frontend/Magento/<my_custom_theme_name>/layout/default.xml but still magento ignoring my layout file changes. i have follow the official doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html anyone know the better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add below content in default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

path : `magento/vendor/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme‌​/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
```

after added content open terminal(Command promt) ctrl+Alt+t

Run below commands :

1. sudo cd /project_path_directory/
2. sudo php bin/magento
   setup:static-content:deploy
3. sudo php bin/magento
   indexer:reindex
4. sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
5. sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
6. sudo rm -rf var/*